# Renamed project failing

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have taken a copy of an existing project (Door), with the expectation of using some of the core features for a supervisor application (Mgmt).

I have renamed the project from Door to Mgmt.
I have visited every visible file and changed references to the old application name.
I have done a global search and replace for the old app name.
I have also opened project.pbxproj and found over 10 references to the old project name and changed them. I have also edited xcschemes .xcscheme file name and the cxschememanagement.plist file. As I wish to use push, I have a new certificate for the new app

Everything appears fine, however.......

When I run the application it fails because it cannot find the view controller under the old applications name. (DoorViewController). For the life of me, I cannot see where this is referenced from. the error message is shown below....

```
[Switching to process 7171 thread 0x1c03]
Re-enabling shared library breakpoint 1
2011-11-30 12:18:17.128 mgmt[9706:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/EE73FFD1-5392-41F6-A8CB-706D042EF134/mgmt.app> (loaded)' with name 'DoorViewController''
```

Obviously there is one more thing missing, however it is not something I can see. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

./mgmt.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/user.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate and buried in the mainwindow.xib

```
        <object class="IBUIViewController" id="578626022">
            <string key="IBUINibName">DoorViewController</string>
```

Manually edited the xib file using a text editor and deleted the xcuserstate file got the app started. I am surprised that the IBUIViewController setting was not visible with a global search, nor within IB, however.......

Thanks sanjay.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you tried this:

Open MainWindow.xib
On left column, under objects:
Do you see "Door View Controller"?

What is its class as per the identity inspector? (<kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>command</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd>)

If it's still DoorViewController, change it to the new one.

If this doesn't work, delete "Door View Controller", drag & drop a new one from the library and then change its identity.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, however the MainWindow.xib objects are window, Mgmt View Controller and  Mgmt App delegate. Window has class UIWindow, Mgmt View Controller = MgmtViewController and Mgmt App Delegate = MgmtAppDelegate. All appears straight and correct.

Comment: Next thing to try: Open Terminal, navigate to the directory containing your project and execute the following command: `find . -type f -exec grep -l DoorViewController {} \;` This will give you a list of files containing DoorViewController in them. It'll be more thorough search than xcode's global search.